# Less than relationship of natural numbers

Tags: coq

I want to prove the following two lemmas. Same hypothesis for both. I have tried these two lemmas lt_le_S n m & le_not_lt n m. In order to prove first lemma I have to add some relation of i5 in hypothesis?

```
 Theorem Si6_Si5_lt0:forall (i6 i5:nat),
  (S i6 =? 0) = false->
  S i6 < S i5.

 Theorem Si6_lt0:forall (i6 :nat),
  (S i6 =? 0) = false->
  (S i6)<0.
```

Comment: Why are you mixing propositional and boolean relations? I see no reason to use boolean equality here. Juste write `S i6 <> 0`.

Answer (score 4):

Well the theorems aren't true.  The first one says "forall i j, if false=false then i < j" which is not true, and the second one says "forall i, if false=false then i+1 < 0" which also is not true.

Comment: I have hypothesis false=false for above both lemmas.It can help in closing wrong statement of goal.

Comment: No. `false=false` doesn't provide any information about the integers `i5` and `i6`.

Answer (score 0):

As @larsr said, both theorems are not true/unprovable.
Maybe pointing out what is not true/tautology might help you.

```
 Theorem Si6_Si5_lt0:forall (i6 i5:nat),
  (S i6 =? 0) = false->
  S i6 < S i5.
```

You might notice that your premise is actually a theorem.

```
Theorem S_is_not_0 : forall i6, (S i6 =? 0) = false.
  easy.
Qed.
```

'=?' operator is fine if you really need a program, but for the most part of proofs you only need irrelevance-proofs definitions, so changing to the usual reflexive definition might help you to prove your theorem, once the not proof-irrelevance definitions are not equipped with theorems already proved or automation by specialized tactics.

Well if your premise is a theorem that can be proved without any dependency so it doesn't need to be together with your theorem, and in your case, it will not help your theorem at all.

So your lemma is actually :

```
Theorem Si6_Si5_lt0:forall (i6 i5:nat),
      S i6 < S i5.
```

And of course, it is unprovable(aka (Si6_Si5_lt0 9 8) : 10 < 9).
The second theorem is false, however, it can be fixed using a negation :

```
    Theorem Si6_lt0:forall (i6 :nat),
      ~ (S i6)<0.
  intros.
  intro h.
  inversion h.
Qed.
```

I think you're trying to prove something bigger, you can reformulate your question with your actual theorem that you want to finish.

Comment: I am using count function from Coq library and want to prove
count (S i6) l < count (0) l   & count (S i6) l < count (S i5) l.

in the presence of following hypothesis (i5<i6 &  0<i6)

Comment: But.. you need to know something about `l` to be able to prove that!

Comment: All elements in the list are zero and mimimum one element  present in the list. It means occurence of zero is greater than than any non zero element of list.

Comment: How to prove  that presence of  non zero(S n) number in the list (containing all 0s) is zero. and this number  is less than count of zero in the list@larsr